# Force <span> to stay in <td>

Tags: html-table, html

I am trying to keep the text in this span from going out of the td. Is there a way to do this?

```
<table style="height:62px; overflow:hidden; border-style:solid; border-width:thick; table-layout:fixed; width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:256px"></td>
            <td valign="top" style="border-style:solid; border-width:thick"> <span style="font-size:20px;">
                    wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
                </span>

            </td>
            <td style="width: 180px"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqr4n/1/

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap or be hidden?

Comment: I would perfer an ellipses but hidden works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;` to your table cell.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vqr4n/7/)**

Answer (score 2):

To break it:

```
td{ word-wrap: break-word; }
```

To hide it:

```
td{ overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; }
```

More info about [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.crop 
{
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
}​
```